# How to display png files and csv tables in a python (dash) dashboard

Tags: python-3.x, button, drop-down-menu, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am very new to plotly and dash as well as UI. I have collected data form twitter using tweepy and have completed the analysis and generated some pngs also.

I am trying to build a dashboard now. I have a list of images(png) and a list files (csv).
I want to have one button  "charts" and dropdown list "data" (basically csv files) in the dashboard.

If I click on "charts", I want to display all the images (around 3) and if I select one file, then I want to just display top 100 lines of csv in a table.

Can someone just suggest a skeleton for this and hence I can build on top of it. I did go through some examples for button from https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/button and others and tried as below.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import base64

app = dash.Dash()

list_of_images = [
    "C:\\Users\\results\\sentiment_plot.png",
    "C:\\Users\\positive_wc.png",
    "C:\\Users\\negative_wc.png",
    "C:\\Users\\top_hashtag.png"
]

list_of_data = [
    "C:\\Users\\sentiment_by_location.csv",
    "C:\\Users\\geo_location_frequency.csv",
    "C:\\Users\\total_hashtag_frequency.csv",
]

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Twitter analytics Report'),
    html.H2(children='''Image charts'''),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='image-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in list_of_images],
        # initially display the first entry in the list
        value = list_of_images[0],
    ),
    html.Img(id='image'),

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='data-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in list_of_data],
        # initially display the first entry in the list
        value = list_of_data[0]
    ),
    html.Img(id='data')

])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('image', 'src'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('image-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_image_src(image_path):
    # print the image_path to confirm the selection is as expected
    print('current image_path = {}'.format(image_path))
    encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open(image_path, 'rb').read())
    return 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode())

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('data', 'src'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('data-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_data_src(data_path):
    # print the image_path to confirm the selection is as expected
    print('current data_path = {}'.format(data_path))
    encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open(data_path, 'rb').read())
    return 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The above example works for imgaes but still I have to find a way to make all the images display inthe same size.
Csv I only have a list of drop down. I haven't found a way to show the csv data in a tabular form.

It's still overwhelming for me to try my use case as above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried from another example as below. This also never display images.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import base64

# Launch the application:
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Clear', id='btn-nclicks-1', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('sentiment_plot', id='btn-nclicks-2', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('top_hashtag', id='btn-nclicks-3', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('positive_wc', id='btn-nclicks-4', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('negative_wc', id='btn-nclicks-5', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-timestamp')
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('container-button-timestamp', 'children'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('btn-nclicks-1', 'n_clicks'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('btn-nclicks-2', 'n_clicks'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('btn-nclicks-3', 'n_clicks'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('btn-nclicks-4', 'n_clicks'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('btn-nclicks-5', 'n_clicks')
)
def displayClick(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5):
    changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]
    if 'btndisplayClick-nclicks-1' in changed_id:
        ### HAVE TO CLEAR THE CANVAS
        msg = 'None was clicked'
    if 'btn-nclicks-2' in changed_id:
        #msg = 'sentiment_plot was most recently clicked'
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open("C:\\Users\\sentiment_plot.png", 'rb').read())
        msg = 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode())
    elif 'btn-nclicks-3' in changed_id:
        #msg = 'top_hashtag was most recently clicked'
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open("C:\\Users\\top_hashtag.png", 'rb').read())
        msg = 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode())
    elif 'btn-nclicks-4' in changed_id:
        #msg = 'positive_wc was most recently clicked'
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open("C:\\Users\\positive_wc.png", 'rb').read())
        msg = 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode())
    elif 'btn-nclicks-5' in changed_id:
        #msg = 'negative_wc was most recently clicked'
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open("C:\\Users\\negative_wc.png", 'rb').read())
        msg = 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode())
    else:
        msg = 'None of the buttons have been clicked yet'
    return html.Div(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```